# how to prevent numerous background daemons from harming gaming FPS (or other intense foreground workload performance)?

Tags: macos, performance, cpu, multitasking, daemons

One or another of the various macOS background daemons that comes with the operating system is always popping up and using a ton of CPU in the background.  This is generally slightly bothersome, but it's *really* annoying while I'm trying to play demanding video games that really need the system's full attention.  This visibly hurts the framerate and I need to go and investigate in iStat Menus or something to nuke the offending process manually.

Is there a way to comprehensively pause or at least aggressively throttle *all* system background activity while I'm doing something demanding?  Mostly I want this for applications that are demanding of input responsiveness, like video games, but it would be nice for CPU intensive batch jobs that might take an hour or two to run, too; tell the system to please chill out in the background and not suck up either CPU or I/O to let the jobs run either more repsonsively or faster.

I'm being non-specific because “Why is daemon X taking up so much CPU” is a common genre of question on this site and others like it ([previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387555/suggestd-taking-too-much-memory-overnight-on-10-14-mojave), [previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108096/mdworker-process-always-at-100-even-when-not-indexing), [previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338159/calendaragent-hogs-cpu-to-100-every-time-i-get-network-connection), [previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390437/what-is-privateframeworks-deleted-and-why-is-it-using-so-much-cpu), [previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199151/background-processes-periodically-eat-up-my-cpu-time-on-os-x-10-10-4-yosemite), [previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44720/fseventsd-is-at-100cpu-when-time-machine-on-external-hard-drive-is-connected), [previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429693/macos-opendirectoryd-constantly-running-taking-up-cpu), [previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432075/syspolicyd-cpu-usage-drains-the-battery), [previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147073/very-frequent-cpu-usage-100-for-systemstats), [previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49715/process-ubd-high-cpu-usage), [previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380446/mac-os-catalina-10-15-2-ampdevicesagent-using-100-cpu)).  *All* of these daemons are implicated at various points.  Probably the worst offenders are `syspolicyd`, `AMPDevicesAgent`, and worst of all `suggestd`, but all the usual suspects show up at one point or another.

As such, I'm not looking for a *permanent* answer for how to fix these problems all the time, i.e. how to make these daemons go away, because:

1. There's too many of them; I am resigned to just having weird energy leaks and performance problems until Apple provides some more transparency for their background daemons.
2. At least for right now, they're *mostly* behaving themselves *most* of the time, and I realize they provide value by indexing things and doing stuff in the background to provide responsiveness in the moment.
3. With an Apple Silicon machine, they appear to mostly be persistently scheduled onto the Efficiency cores and have less of a devastating performance and battery impact than they used to, as a result.

What I'm looking for is more of a *temporary* fix for when I need maximum performance, which would allow me to simply quiet down the background performance interference rather than shutting it down completely.  I know the system needs this stuff to run for all the functionality to work and I don't want to take an axe to necessary parts of the OS, but I'd also like to get a consistent 120 FPS in 5-year-old games without dropping to 2-3FPS for a minute and getting killed because it was *really* important to Mail.app to make sure I could instantly search for some direct marketer's phone number because it downloaded a new message into its spam folder.

Comment: Maybe just shutdown Mail and other applications while you are gaming? Or create a gaming account and log out of the main account to play games?

Comment: The applications are shut down. The Mail.app example is because `suggestd` is scanning Mail’s database, among others, sporadically in the background regardless of whether the app is open. Making a second account has no effect because many of these background services are system-wide and don’t require my main user to be logged in to run and consume CPU.

Comment: We used to run CFD very intensive tasks on Silicon Graphics machine ie Unix, and used 99% of the cpu - the system still has to  do housekeeping even in the background and those tasks would be running for 40 days or more.

Comment: Are we looking at processes which are running all the time, or at processes which get launched, run a few seconds and disappear again til triggered again? The first group you could pause by sending the appropriate signal from Terminal.

Comment: A mix. Systemstats seems to be launched periodically but then exit. AMPDevicesAgent launches when iOS devices are syncing, which is pretty frequent but not always. Suggestd is running all the time, mds seems to have a pool of workers who live for a while and then get periodically reaped. There’s not a really clear pattern.

Comment: @SolarMike I’m fine with leaving the system in a normal state for things that literally run overnight, I’m more considering tasks that run in the 15-45 minute range; where they’re short enough that I might be actively waiting for them to finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this is that it was a missing feature in macOS, and in macOS Sonoma now has [Game Mode, which will have no configuration, but the OS should detect full-screen games and prioritize them](https://appleinsider.com/inside/macos-sonoma/tips/how-apples-game-mode-in-macos-sonoma-works#:%7E:text=For%20macOS%20Sonoma%20to%20turn,an%20actual%20game%20controller%20connected.).

Answer (score 1):

As [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/442275/510859) suggested, using `pkill -STOP suggestd` works just fine. The process will be kept in the state "sleeping" once the command is executed (visible in the activity monitor, but using 0% CPU) (Note: I've checked the processes for more than five days and they were kept in "sleeping" mode.). If you want to prevent such processes from getting activated automatically, add the command into `.bashrc` (or other config). For example, in my case I have the following lines in `.zshrc`:

```
pkill -STOP suggestd
pkill -STOP photoanalysisd
pkill -STOP photolibraryd
pkill -STOP cloudphotod
```

Those processes will be running, but not using any CPU, because they will be "sleeping". You can verify the state yourself by finding the PID of the process and then looking at its state with `top`:

```
pgrep suggestd
# outputs <PID>
top -pid <PID>
# look for column `state`, it should be `sleeping`
```

Comment: This is not a great answer, for a few reasons. Some of these processes will idle out and get killed and restarted if they're hung for too long, which `STOP` will do. Also, this is not a comprehensive catalogue of all the background processes. If you see my comment in the other answer you can see that this is an insufficient list, as it does not include `syspolicyd`, `systemstats`, `mds_stores`, `backupd`, `deleted`, `tccd`, `AMDDevicesAgent`,`AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent`, `usbmuxd`, `cloudphotod`, `photoanalysisd`, `opendirectoryd`, `CalendarAgent`, `sharingd`, `cloudd`, `calaccessd` (and so on)

Comment: First, I didn't restart my macbook for about 5 days and checked the state of the processes I mentioned above regularly (about twice a day). **None** of those processes were restarted and have been kept "sleeping". Please try out sleeping the processes and report back if it does **not** work.

Second, I did not claim that this is an exhaustive list. I gave examples. Further services can be looked up via activity monitor (the ones that cause an FPS drop). Note that the person who asked this question is not looking for a "blanket answer" either.

Comment: I am the person who asked the question. My phrasing with "blanket answer" about "fixing" the problems was awkward. I'll edit the question at some point, but what I was trying to express was that I did not want a *fix* to make these daemons go away, since that would break functionality, what I wanted was a temporary pause button.

Comment: I should also say, though, thank you @dichotomies for doing that investigative work, that's a lot of effort to verifying our understanding here!

Answer (score 0):

You can pause long-running background processes like `suggestd` by running

```
pkill -STOP suggestd
```

To let it continue, use `pkill -CONT suggestd` (or reboot).

Comment: The major problem with this answer is that many of the processes are either periodically restarted, spawned on demand, or heartbeating and killed/restarted if they don’t respond. It varies per daemon which is why I’m looking for a system-wide setting.

Comment: @glyph there is no system-wide setting. Please list all relevant processes in the question so people can find a solution.

Comment: I am not sure I can fully enumerate the list (the whole point here is that I don't want to learn about each new CPU leak by hitting a nasty frame drop in the middle of a multiplayer game), but off the top of my head: `syspolicyd`, `systemstats`, `mds_stores`, `backupd`, `deleted`, `tccd`, `AMDDevicesAgent`, `usbmuxd`, `cloudphotod`, `photoanalysisd`, `opendirectoryd`, `CalendarAgent` .

Comment: @glyph Please add this to the question then. LaunchDaemons can be paused as well usually, so it basically a little script which stops/restarts processes and daemons. A script you may need to extend if you find additional processes.