# macOS is limiting FPS for games

Tags: macos, applications, games

I've noticed a lot that when I'm playing games like Minecraft, or scrolling through a page in my browser, it randomly starts 'jittering' or lagging. In Minecraft, the F3 menu exists. It tells me my game is running at 60 FPS, so there shouldn't be this weird jitter. I'm using an M1 MacBook Pro.

It's not the refresh rate, because when I open FrameMeter (from Quartz Debug), the gauge is at 40 FPS even though the game reports 60 FPS? No matter if I look at the ground or disconnect from the server I'm in, macOS still limits it.

This happens on my browser (Brave Browser) and on other apps like Finder, Mail, Steam, MultiMC, Discord, Chrome, Firefox, IntelliJ IDEA, etc. As I'm editing this question to add this paragraph in, FrameMeter gauge is going from 24 FPS to 32 FPS when I type and then going back down when I'm not.

So, **my question is**, how do I stop macOS from automatically limiting framerate/refresh rate for apps?

[image: gauge pointing towards 40]

Comment: What Mac model is this? Are you using an external display? (If so, what specs and connection?) Also which browser? Have you tried a different one?

Comment: M1 MacBook Pro (2020); No I'm not; Brave Browser; Yes, Firefox, Chrome, etc. same result though :(

Comment: Have you tried Safari? It's possible that the jitter is independent of the reported frame rate. Check Activity Monitor to see the GPU History, and if CPU or RAM is being maxed out.

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/442265/9058

Comment: Thanks, @nohillside. I'm taking a look at it now, and I'll tell you if it might be a duplicate. :)

Comment: It seems like logging in and out magically fixes it? Strange.

Comment: @WhatTheClown That suggests an issue in the user domain. Could be a preference, conflicting software, or cache.

Comment: Right, OK. Well, I'll keep this question open in case it happens again/if it happens again.